# Unable to open or close accordian when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angular and I just created an animated accordian with javascript to fetch and display some info. I decided to use ng-repeat so I don't have to write the codes repeatedly.

However the accordian failed to animate to show the contents. Why is that when i use ng-repeat it did not work ? Is it something to do with the way angular works?

Please help, thanks

Here is an example

https://fiddle.jshell.net/ppw2fag9/1/

Comment: Have you investigated `ng-click` as an alternative?  Its probably considered bad practice to mix angularjs with native javascript like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Angular in this way, the Angular generated DOM is not populated until after the code runs, so you are not placing event listeners on the `ng-repeat` DOM elements. You should not modify the DOM with query selectors, instead you should add an `ng-click` directive to the `ng-repeated` element.

The quick way to do what you want do will look like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "John",
    "Tyrion",
    "Khaleesi",
  ];
  
  $scope.toggleText= function(e) {
   var btn = angular.element(e.target);
    var panel = btn.next();
    
   btn.toggleClass("active");

    if (panel.css('maxHeight')){
      panel.css('maxHeight', null);
    } else {
      panel.css('maxHeight', panel.prop('scrollHeight') + 'px');
    } 
  }
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h2>With ng-repeat</h2>
<div ng-repeat="y in records">
<button class="accordion" ng-click="toggleText($event)">{{y}}</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Some explaination...bla bla blah</p>
</div>
```